# OneDrive Sync Feature - Office 365

Tags: onedrive-for-business

Is it possible to TURN OFF the sync feature for the OneDrive for Business as a Global Administrator on SharePoint Online. 
I have to turn off per user, but still the User will be able to Turn it back ON if he knows it.

Thank you
Sangeetha

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no tenant-wide Turn OFF feature for OneDrive. As a workaround, you can use a combination of CSS and jQuery to hide it from DOM. Create a CustomAction to hide it from ribbon and ECB but you'll need to deploy the wsp package it to all site collections. For the personal MySites, there's not much we can do.

Comment: Can you please let me know how i can use the CSS & jQuery ? Figured out the id of the SYNC button which is QCB1_Button3

But where can i include the jQuery and the hiding CSS $("#QCB1_Button3").hide()

Thank you.

Comment: You can include in it your custom CSS/jquery file referenced in your master page.

Comment: Not sure which masterpage does the OneDrive uses :(